# Rails loop on two div

Tags: ruby-on-rails, loops

I have an issue with my loop on a Bootstrap tab.

```html
%ul.nav.nav-pills.nav-fill{role: "tablist"}
  - @matrices.each_with_index do |matrice, i|
    %li.nav-item
      = link_to "#matrice_#{matrice.id}", class:"nav-link #{"active show" if i.zero?}", "data-toggle" => "tab" do
         = matrice.name
.tab-content
  - @matrices.each_with_index do |matrice, i|
    %div{id:"matrice_#{matrice.id}", class:"tab-pane #{"active show" if i.zero?}", role: "tabpanel"}
      = matrice.name
```

First tab is display well with the content but when I click on the second tab, first tab content is also display. I want to hide the previous tab content at click.

How to fix it? Can I make one loop over two HTML div?

Comment: What do you mean by "Keep in memory" are you saying that the div is not hiding or you want to remove the div when they click on another tab and then render a new one?

Comment: Yes, I want to remove the div when click on another tab and then render a new one

Answer (score 0):

Haml strictly follows indentation. Seems the loop in the second tab is put under same line where first tab is.

Try the below way.

```
%ul.nav.nav-tabs
  %li.active
    %a{"data-toggle": "tab", href: "#tab_menu1"}
      Graphical View
  %li
    %a{"data-toggle": "tab", href: "#tab_menu2"}
      Tabular View

%div.tab-content
  %div.tab-pane.in.active{id: "tab_menu1"}
    = render partial: "menu1_view"
  %div.tab-pane{id: "tab_menu2"}
    = render partial: "menu2_view"
```

You can refer https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_tabs_pills.asp for more details.

Add your loops under the %div.tab-page tag.

Hope this helps!!